# What is the reason for why sites when opening a user link, open a page and then redirects?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, redirect

For example Facebook redirects if you click on a link one of you friends shared.

Is there a safety reason that I should know about for my website? Thanks.

Comment: The answer could be a combination of both what PAULDAWG and Drew Dahlman are saying, i.e **place, security and tracking** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using this to track, you can also use it to track traffic - there shouldn't be any real security issues with this, its just the way Facebook directs traffic to sites.

Answer (score 1):

One reason is that the user doesn't lose their place on the site just because they are going to another web page. It's a usability best practice to have any link that goes to a site other than your own, to open a new window or tab.

Security-wise, the site session on the new window is wiped when a new window is created, so if the link is malicious it cant sniff out your authentication cookies or other information.